Could a $C_c^{\infty}$ function be homogeneous of degress $-n$?

Does there exist a function that belongs to $ C_c^{\infty} $ and is homogeneous of degree $ -n $? If so, can you provide a concrete example?

In the weak sense, does there exist a function that belongs to the Schwartz space $ \mathcal{S} $ and is homogeneous of degree $ -n $?

In general, does there exist a function that belongs to $ C_c^{\infty} $ and is homogeneous of degree $ k $, where $ k \neq 0 $?



What do you mean by "in the weak sense" ? The schwartz space $\mathcal{S}$ is traditionally defined as a set of $C^\infty$ functions with faster than polynomial decay for all derivatives.

If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $-\lambda$ with $\lambda > 0$, then $f = 0$ or $f$ is not continuous at $0$. Indeed, by homogeneity, for all $x \neq 0$, we have
$$|f(tx)| = t^{-\lambda}|f(x)|$$
But if $f$ is continuous at $0$, then $\lim_{t \to 0} |f(tx)| = |f(0)|$. Thus it must be that $f(x) = 0$ (otherwise $t^{-\lambda} |f(x)|$ is unbounded as $t \to 0$), and consequently, $f(0) = 0$, so $f = 0$.
In general, if $f$ is homogeneous of degree $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ (even $\lambda > 0$) then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all $t > 0$
$$|f(tx)| = t^\lambda |f(x)|$$
If $f$ is compacly supported, then there is $t$ such that $tx \notin \text{supp}(f)$, so $f(tx) = 0$. Thus, $f(x) = 0$ (because $t^\lambda \neq 0$). So any compactly supported function which is homogeneous of degree $\lambda$ must vanish. This answers 1. and 3.
On the other hand, suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is homogeneous of degree $\lambda$ and in the Schwartz class $\mathcal{S}$. For all $n$, there exists $M_n > 0$ such that
$$|x|^{2n} |f(x)| \leq M_n$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $|x|^2 = x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2$. For all $t > 0$, we have
$$|tx|^{2n} |f(tx)| = t^{2n+\lambda} |x|^{2n}|f(x)|.$$
Choose $n > \frac{1 - \lambda}{2}$ and let $C_n := |x|^{2n}|f(x)|$. For all $t > 0$, we must have
$$t C_n \leq t^{2n + \lambda} C_n =  |tx|^2 |f(tx)| \leq M_n$$
which implies that $C_n = 0$. So for all $x \neq 0$, it follows that $f(x) = 0$, and so $f = 0$ by continuity. This answers 2.

The requirement of -n homogeneity, expressed as f(tx) = t-nf(x) for all x ∈ Rn and t > 0, dictates that as |x| approaches infinity, the function f(x) must decay at a rate proportional to |x|-n. However, if f(x) is also required to be C∞ (infinitely differentiable), this smoothness constraint, particularly when combined with the behavior near the origin, leads to a contradiction. Specifically, the rapid decay required by -n homogeneity necessitates that the function and all its derivatives approach zero as |x| goes to infinity. This, coupled with the requirement that the function is smooth everywhere (including at the origin), implies that the function must be identically zero
Consider the following three examples and the relaxation of conditions under which they exhibit homogeneity. Only the second example strictly satisfies the conditions in the rigorous sense
1.f(x) = 1/(1 + |x|2)n/2, where x ∈ Rm (m is any positive integer), and |x| denotes the Euclidean norm of x
The denominator of this function is always non-zero, and it is a composition of a polynomial and a smooth function. Therefore, it is a C∞ function. When |x| is large, f(tx) ≈ 1/(t2|x|2)n/2 = t-n * 1/|x|n, approximately exhibiting homogeneity of degree -n. Strictly speaking, this function is not a homogeneous function in the strict sense, but it exhibits homogeneity of degree -n "at infinity."
2.In the one-dimensional case, δ'(tx) = (1/t2)δ'(x), i.e., homogeneity of degree -2
The Dirac delta function itself is a generalized function (or distribution), defined in the weak sense. Its derivative is also a generalized function. The derivative of the delta function is well-defined when acting on functions in the Schwartz space S, and the derivative of the delta function exhibits homogeneity. In higher dimensions, the derivatives of the delta function of various orders also exhibit corresponding negative homogeneity.
3.f(x) = |x|k, where x ∈ Rm, and k is any real number
f(tx) = |tx|k = |t|k|x|k. When t > 0, f(tx) = tkf(x), satisfying homogeneity of degree k. When k is a non-negative even integer, this function is a polynomial and is clearly C∞. When k is any other real number, the function is also C∞ in the region x ≠ 0. However, at x = 0, the derivatives may not exist or be continuous when k is not a non-negative even integer. It is clearly not a strictly C∞ homogeneous function. We relax the conditions for it to hold; otherwise, there are no concrete correct examples
4.A construction intended to encompass the above three cases, but which is not a concrete example in the strict sense, is: F(x) = ψ(x)hk,ε(x) + (1 - ψ(x))g-n(x)
Here, ψ(x) is a smooth cutoff function (e.g., a smooth bump function) such that ψ(x) = 1 for |x| ≪ 1 and ψ(x) = 0 for |x| ≫ 1. hk,ε(x) is a smooth approximation of |x|k (e.g., (|x|2 + ε2)k/2 for small ε > 0), and g-n(x) is a function behaving like |x|-n at infinity. F(x) is C∞. When |x| ≪ 1, F(x) approximately exhibits homogeneity of degree k. When |x| ≫ 1, F(x) approximately exhibits homogeneity of degree -n (in the sense of generalized functions). F(x) is compatible with the Schwartz space in the weak sense

$|x|^k$ is not a polynomial. Take $k = 1$. It is also not $C^\infty$, as it is not differentiable at $0$.

Thank you for pointing out the error. Only the zero function rigorously satisfies the given conditions. Other functions can, at best, avoid the origin. Consequently, I have revised my constructed example accordingly. I would appreciate it if you could review section 4 for any inaccuracies, even though I haven't provided a concrete, non-trivial example
